# Create VSIX Project in VS2015 -

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I try to create a new VSIX Project in VS 2015, as shown below:

[image]

I get the following error message immediately:
[image]

The technical manager at work installed VS2015 yesterday, and then I installed the SDK this morning. I tried googling for "Customizing Project Templates" but what I could find did not seem relevant to fixing this error. 
I suppose that this should work out of the box, if the SDK is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I repaired the Visual Studio 2015 installation and that took away the pop-up error.

More detail: I went to 'Programs and Features', right-clicked on the line of the installed VS 2015, and then chose 'Change'. When the option came up to 'Repair', I chose it.